# Oracle update lock

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am in bit confusion regarding update lock, in the below program

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE pro_cedure(
    p_dept_id NUMBER )
IS
  CURSOR mycursor
  IS
    SELECT deptno,comm,extra
    FROM emp
    WHERE comm IS NULL
    AND extra  IS NOT NULL
    AND deptno  = p_dept_id 
    FOR UPDATE OF comm;
BEGIN
  FOR emp_rec IN mycursor
  LOOP
    UPDATE emp SET comm = extra 
    WHERE CURRENT OF mycursor;
    INSERT INTO changed
      (
        deptno,
        oldval,
        newval,
        seq_nextval
      )
      VALUES
      (
        emp_rec.deptno,
        emp_rec.comm,
        emp_rec.extra,
        sequence_name.nextval
      );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

if some other user try to update the same table or the same row while I am updating does it causes a lock with this program?

Comment: SQL commands that write data (update, inserd, delete) place locks on modified rows. Locks remain active until commit or rollback is issuded. If another session (user) is trying to modify locked record, the session is suspended and must wait until the lock is removed by another session.

Comment: You don't need a cursor for this, you can reduce the whole procedure to two simple statements.

Comment: yes, but i need to insert into changed table , as old value and new value in a single procedure.

Comment: You can still do this with just two statements. The loop is very inefficient

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name  how can u please show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run this procedure 2 times parallel, the second wont execute the select until the first commits. (Of course if you run other statements with the same for update of comm clause they will be queued the same way.)

Comment: what if the row is unique while updating for each different p_dept_id input to the above procedure ? still the lock will effect.

Comment: Only the selected rows will be locked. So if you call this procedure with different p_dept_id they won't wait each others because they lock different rows.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the answer.was waiting for this answer.